# Windows Setup/Installer Project: Prevent user from changing installation location?

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project

I have a windows setup project for installing software on client machines.  My boss now wants me to modify it so the user can't change the directory of the installation (it's just for one client, so my boss knows their directory structure).

Can I do this in a windows setup project?  I see the ability to change the Application Folder's DefaultLocation value, however I need to completely prevent the user from having the ability to change this path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it you have two approaches on this:

1. You can remove the ApplicationFolder dialog from the install flow in the setup project.
2. Create a basic UI installation by setting the [LIMITUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property directly in the MSI.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to simply remove from the project the predefined dialogs that allow the user to change the install path. You can find the dialogs under "View -> User Interface", in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You best solution is not to limit the ability to change the installation location, but instead provide a scripted install that doesn't even prompt the user.

e.g. a batch file to call the following command

```
msiexec /i MyApp.msi INSTALLDIR="c:\some\folder" /qb
```

Note that even if you do restrict the user to change the location via the UI, they can always install via the command line and change it with something like the above.